# How to put Japanese Kanji characters into an English document?

Tags: characters

Japanese, please help:

I need to put the following into LaTeX and print it out with pdfLaTeX. The document itself is in English, so I only need a way to put these Kanji characters  (Jin, aza, BUN, MOJI, or so, at least I was told so, I have no clue) into the text. Something like \jin, \aza ... would be great.

```
: (char "a")
-> 97
: (char "字")
-> 23383
: (char 23383)
-> "字"
: (chop "文字")
-> ("文" "字")
: (mapcar char @)
-> (25991 23383)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`CJKutf8`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cjk) package (I wasn't sure about then intended formatting for the other characters, so I left them as they were):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newenvironment{Japanese}{%
  \CJKfamily{min}%
  \CJKtilde
  \CJKnospace}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}
\begin{Japanese}
\noindent: (char ``a'') \\
-> 97 \\
: (char ``字'') \\
-> 23383 \\
: (char 23383) \\
-> ``字'' \\
: (chop ``文字'') \\
-> (``文'' ``字'') \\
: (mapcar char @) \\
```

-> (25991 23383)
    \end{Japanese}
    \end{CJK}

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution, I'm sure it works, but I get other error messages for the document when I try it. So I resorted to an easier solution - include this as a graphic ;)

Comment: Could you please correct the code formatting?